# How to implement ads by more than one networks through mopub in one banner ad android

Tags: android, admob, revmob, mopub, banner-ads

I want to display banner ads by more than one ad providers e.g. admob+revmob through mopub

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to mediate a number of ad networks in one banner ad through MoPub, you can create an account, create an ad unit, and integrate the ad networks you would like to use (For something like AdMob, MoPub already has a built in adapter, so you would need to integrate the SDK if it is not included in the MoPub Full SDK. For RevMob, because the ad network has an SDK, you can write a custom event for the network and integrate into MoPub as a Custom Native Network.)

These networks will show up per ad unit in the Global Segment of MoPub UI's Network tab after closing the "Status:Running" filter. Here you can turn on the ad networks you would like to use for each ad unit you have created.

MoPub has a lot of documentation for getting started on their GitHub and also has help documentation on the twitter developer website, so you should take a look at both those sources.

Edward